# Can I get the Card type from Yodlee transaction received via API?

Tags: yodlee

Is it possible to get payment methods card type from Yodlee API? For e.g., like Visa, Cash etc.

I don't see card type present in transaction details. Can you please provide me the details about how to get the card type? And from which API, URL and field will this information.

Answer (score 0):

Card Type is not part of Yodlee's transaction data model and hence you will not find it present in transaction details.

Card type is actually part of account level information for a card account but it's population rate is very very low. You can refer to our [CreditCard data model](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model#Credit_Card)
documentation for more information on the fields provided.